# Как вставить переменную в строку?

Tags: python, requests, переменные

Как добавить в строку переменную?
Переменную ser нужно добавить на место XXX, задумка такова чтобы при вводе айпи  get запрос отправлялся на ip что мы указали

```
import requests

data = {'user': '' ,'text' : '' }
ser = str(input())
response = requests.get('http://XXX/getmessages', params=data)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так:

```
response = requests.get('http://'+input()+'/getmessages', params=data)
```

Вот новый код:

```
import requests

data = {'user': '' ,'text' : '' }
response = requests.get('http://'+input()+'/getmessages', params=data)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

***Получилось сокращение на строку***

Comment: это, как сказал @CrazyElf, через `+`

Answer (score 1):

В современном питоне есть `f-строки`:

```
ser = input() # input и так выдаёт строку, преобразовывать не нужно
response = requests.get(f'http://{ser}/getmessages', params=data)
```

В более старых версиях тоже есть варианты - соединять строки через `+` либо использовать старые варианты форматирования.