# Как добавить input к переменной

Tags: python

```
deposite = input('')
URL = 'https://minfin.com.ua/deposits/?amount='
```

Надо чтобы deposite вставал на место в конце ссылки

Comment: URL + deposite ...

Comment: К сожалению...( Так просто не работает((

Comment: пачиму..........

Comment: его надо было типизировать как str и все заработало, спасибо большое!

Comment: так `input()` и так всегда строку дает

Comment: `URL = f'https://minfin.com.ua/deposits/?amount={deposite}'`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вставить переменную в строку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1348485/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83)

Answer (score 1):

можно так

```
deposite = input('')
URL = f'https://minfin.com.ua/deposits/?amount={deposite}'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
desp = input()
URL = 'https://minfin.com.ua/deposits/?amount=' + desp
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так:

```
deposite = input('введите что-то: ')
URL = 'https://minfin.com.ua/deposits/?amount=%s' %(deposite)
print(URL)
```